# Sort out file based on a column in another file

Tags: r, sorting

I have a big dataframe looking like this (simplified) :

**File 1:**

```
1 ID   Apo1  Apo2  description Symbol
2 12   0.983 0.675  proteinA    AAG
3 34   0.876 0.123  ProteinB   BEH
4 54   0.432 0.445  proteinC   CFD
5 65   0.544 0.103  ProteinD   DDS
```

Now I want to sort this file out and have only the rows that contain certain "symbols" in the "symbol column ( in this case column 4)
The symbols that I want to get out are in file 2 ( simplified)

**File 2:**

```
AAG
CFD
DDS
```

So I want to get a new file  looking like this , so containing only the rows of file 1 that are linked to the symbols of file 2 in their symbol column:

**new file:**

```
1 ID   Apo1  Apo2  description Symbol
2 12   0.983 0.675  proteinA    AAG
4 54   0.432 0.445  proteinC    CFD
5 65   0.544 0.103  ProteinD    DDS
```

Comment: It's not a sort, it's a filter. What tools have you got are your disposition? I.e., what environment are you working in?

Comment: I use R, I have already tried the subset function                           GeneProtein <- subset(Genefile, UnigeneID == UnigeneF) Genfile being file 1 and UnigeneF file 2 , UnigeneID is the column in Genefile where the symbol is in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering a data frame on a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350025/filtering-a-data-frame-on-a-vector)