# How do I filter a data.frame for specific data points using a vector?

Tags: r, filter, time-series

I have a data.frame called test_data with the following columns:

```
TimeBarStart = times ranging from 04:00 to 19:59 (in minutes)
TimeBarStart2 = 1:960 (minute #) (i.e. 04:00 is 1, 19:59 is 960)
```

I have a vector:

```
start = c("04:00", "09:00", "09:30", "09:30", "15:30", "16:00", "16:00")
```

I am trying to get the TimeBarStart2 values using TimeBarStart values filtered by start.

This seemed to be closest to what I was looking for: [Filtering a data frame on a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350025/filtering-a-data-frame-on-a-vector)

It didn't work though. I got a "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" error. And it returned, strangely enough, the values for 04:00, 15:30 and 16:00, but not the others)

Here's what got me that result:

```
test_data[test_data$TimeBarStart == start,]
```

I would like to see:

```
1, 301, 331, 331, 691, 721, 721
```

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==`  `test_data[test_data$TimeBarStart %in% start,]`

Comment: But **objects have types**! Numbers 1:960 (denoting minute numbers, from midnight) are different to the strings `"04:00", "09:00"...`, which are again different to R `datetime`s, which are again different to other R time objects e.g. `stats::time`, or `zoo` objects. **If you want to compare objects of different types, (in general) first you have to convert one of them to the type of the other.** R's comparison operators are not type-free fuzzy AI matches ;-) So first you need to decide what R type you'll use to represent times (integer? string? datetime? something else?).

Comment: It would help to see the output of `head(dput(YOUR_DATA_FRAME))` in your question, so that we can understand the exact form of your data.